# How to go about finding other login endpoints

Tags: python, web-scraping, endpoint

I am pentesting a website in python and I was wondering how could I go about looking for other login endpoints. Make a brute that just randomizes the start of url like

````
login.(url)
tr.(url)```
or is there another way to find login endpoints
````

Comment: There are many tools out there for this. No need to reinvent the wheel. If you are learning pentesting you should investigate tools such as Kali Linux.

Comment: @packetloss I am familiar with kali linux but i dont know exactly what library id use foir such a task? requests? nmapping?

Comment: Then you need to study pen testing.